# Can I add 3d models on maps in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, 3d, maps

I need to overlay 3D models of buildings I have designed in a separate CAD software. I want to add .stl or .obj files with proper scaling on the 2D map on qgis so that I can make a 3D map with 2D base image. Is it possible in QGIS? If yes, how do I go about it? if not, what other alternatives do I have for doing this?